# conditionally render a component inside tabs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing admin panel for hotel backend

here I want to check the verified status and render accordingly

here is what I did

```
    const AdminDashboard = () => {
        return (
            <>
                <DashboardWrapper>
                    <h1 className="title1 text-center mb-4">Admin Dashboard</h1>;
                    {Object.values(hotel).map((item) => {
                        if (item.verifiedStatus === "verified") {
                            return <AdminCard key={item._id} item={item} />;
                        }
                        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
                            <TabPane tab="Pending" key="1" className="tabs"></TabPane>

                            <TabPane tab="Verified" key="2" className="tabs"></TabPane>
                            <TabPane tab="Rejected" key="3" className="tabs">
                                Rejected Hotels
                            </TabPane>
                        </Tabs>;
                    })}
                </DashboardWrapper>
            </>
        );
    };
```

it is now currently showing verified hotels but I want to move that logic to tabs

```
if (item.verifiedStatus === "verified") {
                            return <AdminCard key={item._id} item={item} />;
                        }
```

I want to check above condition and render in respective tabs

here is output screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same condition in Tabs defaultActiveKey. Use TabPane key to same as verifiedStatus coming from backend. Use the item.Verified Condition in defaultActiveKey.

For Ex:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={item.verifiedStatus}>
 <TabPane tab="Pending" key="pending" className="tabs"></TabPane>

                            <TabPane tab="Verified" key="verified" className="tabs"></TabPane>
                            <TabPane tab="Rejected" key="rejected" className="tabs">
                                Rejected Hotels
                            </TabPane>
                        </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how it worked for me

```
<DashboardWrapper>
                    <h1 className="title1 text-center mb-4">Admin Dashboard</h1>;
                    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
                        {Object.values(hotel).map((item) => {
                            if (item.verifiedStatus === "pending") {
                                return (
                                    <TabPane tab="Pending" key="pending" className="tabs">
                                        <AdminCard key={item._id} item={item} />;
                                    </TabPane>
                                );
                            } else if (item.verifiedStatus === "verified") {
                                return (
                                    <TabPane tab="verified" key="verified" className="tabs">
                                        <AdminCard key={item._id} item={item} />;
                                    </TabPane>
                                );
                            } else {
                                return (
                                    <TabPane tab="rejected" key="rejected" className="tabs">
                                        <AdminCard key={item._id} item={item} />;
                                    </TabPane>
                                );
                            }
                        })}
                    </Tabs>
                    ;
                </DashboardWrapper>
```